# Postgres - Performance of large jsonb column

Tags: json, performance, postgresql, indexing, jsonb

We are using Postgres jsonb type in one of our DB tables. Table structure is shown as below:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
  id UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  payload JSONB
);

CREATE INDEX ON T USING gin (payload jsonb_path_ops);
```

`Payload` is a complex json string. Below is one example:

```
{
    "business": {
        "taxId": "626642071",
        "legalName": "Jon's Deli",
        "phoneNumbers": [
            {
                "phoneType": "Business",
                "telephoneNumber": "8384407555"
            },
            {
                "phoneType": "Work",
                "telephoneNumber": "6032255248"
            }
        ],
        "addresses": [
            {
                "city": "San Francisco",
                "state": "CA",
                "postalCode": "94101",
                "countryCode": "USA",
                "addressLine1": "123 Market St"
            }
        ]
    },
    "stakeholders": [
        {
            "person": {
                "taxId": "540646815",
                "firstName": "GdXFouh",
                "lastName": "IlUAcgCGz",
                "dateOfBirth": "1980-12-11",
                "emailAddress": "jywxsijgix@qaqmlz.com",
                "phoneNumbers": [
                    {
                        "phoneType": "Mobile",
                        "telephoneNumber": "4901371573"
                    }
                ],
                "addresses": [
                    {
                        "city": "San Francisco",
                        "state": "CA",
                        "postalCode": "94101",
                        "countryCode": "USA",
                        "addressLine1": "123 Market St"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that `phoneNumbers`, `addresses` and `stakeholders` are arrays, which means there can be multiple elements in the array.

I try to insert one million rows into the table. Each field of `payload` is generated **randomly**. Initially the testing program runs very fast. But after inserting about 800,000 rows, it gets stuck every 1000 rows -- insert 1000 rows, then the testing program is hung for 2 minutes, then it comes back and insert another 1000 rows, ...

We are suspecting this is caused by huge amount of jsonb index updates. Because there are many fields to be updated in the index for a single row. We just want to confirm if anyone has met the same problem.

---

Actually we don't need to index the whole `payload` column. Only certain fields are needed: `business->taxId`, `business->phoneNumbers-> telephoneNumber`, `stakeholders->person->taxId` and `stakeholders->person->emailAddress`.

I have tried following two indices:

```
CREATE INDEX ON T USING gin ((payload->'business'->'taxId') jsonb_path_ops);
CREATE INDEX ON T USING gin ((payload ->'stakeholders'->'person'->'taxId') jsonb_path_ops);
```

And run two statements:

```
explain select * from T where payload->'business'->'taxId' @> '"123456789"'; (1)
explain select * from T where payload->'stakeholders'->'person'->'taxId' @> '"123456789"'; (2)
```

The first statement is using the index. But the second one is doing a full table scan which is very slow. That's why we turn to index the whole `payload` column.

---

Any suggestion is welcome.

BTW, we are using Postgres 9.5.4.

Comment: If that payload is going to be consistent, you should consider turning it into a real schema. Postgres will be far more efficient like that. Keep JSONB for when you're not sure what the structure will be, or if the structure is sparse. People, addresses, phone numbers, businesses, and stakeholders are your tables.

Comment: The schema of payload may be changed in the near future. That's why we are saving it as json, instead of doing it in the normalized way.

Answer (score 9):

Your query:

```
select * from T where payload->'stakeholders'->'person'->'taxId' @> '"123456789"';
```

does not work. This is because 'stakeholders' is array. Worked query is:

```
select * from T where payload->'stakeholders' @> '[{"person": {"taxId": "54"}}]'::jsonb
```

But in this case postgres can use use index on whole stakeholders.

```
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on t  (cost=1388.08..1425.90 rows=10 width=36) (actual time=1.959..1.959 rows=1 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((payload -> 'stakeholders'::text) @> '[{"person": {"taxId": "54"}}]'::jsonb)
   Heap Blocks: exact=1
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on t_expr_idx3  (cost=0.00..1388.08 rows=10 width=0) (actual time=1.946..1.946 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((payload -> 'stakeholders'::text) @> '[{"person": {"taxId": "54"}}]'::jsonb)
 Planning time: 0.071 ms
 Execution time: 1.978 ms
```

For using more specific index I use modified approach by: [How do you create a Postgresql JSONB array in array index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087282/how-do-you-create-a-postgresql-jsonb-array-in-array-index)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extract_taxids(a_json jsonb).
RETURNS jsonb AS $BODY$
     SELECT jsonb_agg(j) FROM (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(a_json->'stakeholders')->'person'->'taxId' AS j) AS j
$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
CREATE INDEX ON T USING gin (extract_taxids(payload));
```

And voila:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE select * from T where extract_taxids(payload) @> '["54"]';

                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on t  (cost=12.08..52.38 rows=10 width=36) (actual time=0.101..0.102 rows=1 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (extract_taxids(payload) @> '["54"]'::jsonb)
   Heap Blocks: exact=1
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on t_extract_taxids_idx  (cost=0.00..12.07 rows=10 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (extract_taxids(payload) @> '["54"]'::jsonb)
 Planning time: 0.128 ms
 Execution time: 0.117 ms
```

Comment: I tried your in your way. The `explain` shows it's using the index, which is good. However, the `select` returns empty result, which is actually wrong. I have that row in the table.

Comment: And also what if I only want to index `stakeholder.person.taxId`, how can I create the index. Basically I don't want to index other fields inside `person`.

Comment: Thanks Roman!!! I know this may work. But it looks complicated. I decided to use another way: create a separate column which is a lean json containing only fields we want to index, e.g. taxId, email...

Comment: No problem. It is your question :-)